# Run psexec.exe when username has a hyphen

Tags: active-directory, psexec

I have to invoke a script through psexec which involves using an username that has hyphens in it. Unfortunately, the command does not work and does not throw any understandable error message. It just shows me how I should be using psexec i.e., various arguments and what they stand for.

My command goes something like this -

```
psexec.exe \\hostname -u domain\user-name-acct -p passwd -i 2 <script>
```

I am almost certain that hyphen is the culprit since I am able to invoke the same script by using a username that does not have hyphens. The account has admin privileges on the VM. Before I ask them to create / edit the username not to have hyphens, I just want to make sure that there is no way to run such commands.

**Update - Command Result**

```
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

PsExec executes a program on a remote system, where remotely executed console
applications execute interactively.

Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p psswd][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-<priority>][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]
     -a         Separate processors on which the application can run with
                commas where 1 is the lowest numbered CPU. For example,
                to run the application on CPU 2 and CPU 4, enter:
                "-a 2,4"
     -c         Copy the specified program to the remote system for
                execution. If you omit this option the application
                must be in the system path on the remote system.
     -d         Don't wait for process to terminate (non-interactive).
     -e         Does not load the specified account's profile.
     -f         Copy the specified program even if the file already
                exists on the remote system.
     -i         Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the
                specified session on the remote system. If no session is
                specified the process runs in the console session.
     -h         If the target system is Vista or higher, has the process
                run with the account's elevated token, if available.
     -l         Run process as limited user (strips the Administrators group
                and allows only privileges assigned to the Users group).
                On Windows Vista the process runs with Low Integrity.
     -n         Specifies timeout in seconds connecting to remote computers.
     -p         Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this
                you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.
     -r         Specifies the name of the remote service to create or interact.
                with.
     -s         Run the remote process in the System account.
     -u         Specifies optional user name for login to remote
                computer.
     -v         Copy the specified file only if it has a higher version number
                or is newer on than the one on the remote system.
     -w         Set the working directory of the process (relative to
                remote computer).
     -x         Display the UI on the Winlogon secure desktop (local system
                only).
     -priority  Specifies -low, -belownormal, -abovenormal, -high or
                -realtime to run the process at a different priority. Use
                -background to run at low memory and I/O priority on Vista.
     computer   Direct PsExec to run the application on the remote
                computer or computers specified. If you omit the computer
                name PsExec runs the application on the local system,
                and if you specify a wildcard (\\*), PsExec runs the
                command on all computers in the current domain.
     @file      PsExec will execute the command on each of the computers listed
                in the file.
     cmd            Name of application to execute.
     arguments  Arguments to pass (note that file paths must be
                absolute paths on the target system).
     -accepteula This flag supresses the display of the license dialog.

You can enclose applications that have spaces in their name with
quotation marks e.g. psexec \\marklap "c:\long name app.exe".
Input is only passed to the remote system when you press the enter
key, and typing Ctrl-C terminates the remote process.

If you omit a user name the process will run in the context of your
account on the remote system, but will not have access to network
resources (because it is impersonating). Specify a valid user name
in the Domain\User syntax if the remote process requires access
to network resources or to run in a different account. Note that
the password and command is encrypted in transit to the remote system.

Error codes returned by PsExec are specific to the applications you
execute, not PsExec.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a windows box to test my hypothesis on, but I believe you would enclose the domain\user-name in either single or double quotes:

```
psexec.exe \\hostname -u "domain\user-name-acct" -p passwd -i 2 <script>
```

or possibly:

```
psexec.exe \\hostname -u 'domain\user-name-acct' -p passwd -i 2 <script>
```

However, I would be leaning toward the double quotes.. 
Also, if this does not resolve your issue, perhaps post the errors, even if they are nonsense to you, they may mean something to others.
HTH

Comment: They didn't work. I have updated the errors in my question.

Comment: I just whipped up a VM, and pulled down v2.11 of psexec, and had no issues running the command with hyphens in the username, without single or double quotes..The only difference being I only launched cmd, rather than called a script..

Comment: Are you potentially copying the command from a text editor that is converting the hyphen "-" character to ASCII 227 "—", and then trying to paste that into cmd? Just thinking outside the box, here...

Comment: It finally started working. I used to type the command but this time I started fresh with a new command prompt, re-typed the command and it worked. Not sure what went wrong earlier. Thank you very much for the support.

Comment: Excellent! Well, kind of, anyway.. I'm still a little surprised that the double quotes did not work - as they are the recommended fix for hostnames that have hyphens them, on top of which, I have just tried:
`psexec -u ".\this-is-user" -p somepass cmd` 
and 
`psexec -u .\this-is-user -p somepass cmd` 
and both executed just fine..as you can see, the username in my command also has psexec flags - so it is really quite curious...

Comment: Ah! This time it is excellent!
I was really more than a little perplexed. But pleased you got it working, anyway.
Just ignore my last message - I did not see yours come in until I had submitted it.

Comment: I must also add that in my second attempt, I ran PSExec.exe as administrator. Now the command works fine even without an elevated command prompt. Therefore, I suppose it was something to do with the first time creation of psexec's service. Got the hint when I tried to run the same command in normal prompt in local machine and got an access denied error which was set right once I ran it as administrator.